# Update page before exe runs on server

Tags: c#, asp.net

Here is what I am attempting to make. It's a C# ASP page.

- User picks a date
- User hits "Import"
- An Exe stored in /AppData/ runs
- A status message of "Running" shows on the page **<-- Issue here**
- When the exe closes, the status message says "Done"

Here is my code for the import button:

```
Process[] pDTExport = Process.GetProcessesByName("DTImport");

if (pDTExport.Length != 0)
{
    prgStatus.Visible = false;
    txtStatus.Text = "Unable to import data: another import process is already running. Please wait for it to finish before trying again.";
    txtStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}
else
{
    txtStatus.Text = "The import process is running..."; <-- Issue here
    LaunchExe();
}
```

And how I am launching the exe:

```
    private void LaunchExe()
    {
        string exePath = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/DTImport.exe");

        if (File.Exists(exePath))
        {
            Process pImport = new Process();

            pImport.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
            pImport.StartInfo.Arguments = "-d " + txtDate.Text;
            pImport.Start();

            pImport.WaitForExit();

            txtStatus.Text = "Done!";
            txtStatus.ForeColor = Color.Green;
            prgStatus.Visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            txtStatus.Text = "DTImport.exe was not found in /AppData/"
            txtStatus.ForeColor = Color.Red;
            prgStatus.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

The issue I am having is updating the front end before I launch the exe. I want it to do this: Click button -> Show running message -> Launch exe.

Currently, when I click on the button, the exe runs, but I never see the "Import process is running" message, just the "Done!" line after it finishes.

I know it's because the line

```
pImport.WaitForExit();
```

is blocking the main thread. I tried storing/reading a `ViewState` variable in the `Page_Load` event, to try and launch the exe on the postback causes by the button, but it didn't work. Any ideas how on how I can update the UI before the exe runs?

Comment: Use a WebMethod and periodically call it using jquery and update some div. Web method should be able to determine if something runs. But better that if your exe posts updates periodically and web method checks the update log and then returns the status back to page without postback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register an event Handler to the pImport.Exit event. This allows you to avoid waitForExit. In the registered method you can manage the update to import done.

Comment: Wow. Had no idea that event was there. Thank you!